# Get The Current Time From Website

Tags: java, android

Is there any way to Get the current Time From a [Website](https://greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/gmt-plus-6/) ?

I Have Created a App . I want to Get the current Time . If user change the time Of the device and the time is not equals to the website don't let user to use the app. I don't understanding how to get the current time . i just need help to get the current time of world .

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to output a time stamp in format YYYY.MM.DD-HH.MM.SS (very frequent case) then here's the way to do it:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Comment: i doesn't say that to get the time from device :(

Answer (score 0):

If you need a web API that gives you the actual time you can use timezonedb:

You can get the current time for any timezone

Request

```
http://api.timezonedb.com/v2/get-time-zone?key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=json&by=zone&zone=America/Chicago
```

Response

```
{
    "status":"OK",
    "message":"",
    "countryCode":"US",
    "countryName":"United States",
    "zoneName":"America\/Chicago",
    "abbreviation":"CST",
    "gmtOffset":-21600,
    "dst":"0",
    "dstStart":1446361200,
    "dstEnd":1457856000,
    "nextAbbreviation":"CDT",
    "timestamp":1454446991,
    "formatted":"2016-02-02 21:03:11"
}
```

---

Update: Android example

API Key is a value given to you from the API server when you (free) [register to the website](https://timezonedb.com/register)

I wrote an example for get the data.

```
private Response getServerTime(){
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.timezonedb.com/v2/get-time-zone?key=YOUR_API_KEY&format=json&by=zone&zone=America/Chicago");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;
            while ((s = in.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(s);

        String json = sb.toString();

        Response response = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(in, Response.class);
        return response;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also, create the model for the response

```
public class Response {
    public String status;
    public String message;
    public String countryCode;
    public String countryName;
    public String zoneName;
    public String abbreviation;
    public int gmtOffset;
    public String dst;
    public int dstStart;
    public int dstEnd;
    public String nextAbbreviation;
    public int timestamp;
    public String formatted;
}
```

And add Gson library to your app's build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ..

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
}
```

Comment: Can i use my firebase database to do this?

Comment: firebase databaseis not related to this. In your app, when you need the time from server you just make an HTTP GET call to the URL above and you get the time.

Comment: what is api key?

Comment: And can u please write a method private void CheckTime(){}  by witch app will get the time?

Comment: i want 12h time format and I want to compare it to the device time.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, adding a php page to the web site. I can post some code later, when I go back home.

**ADDED:**

Just create this gettime.php file in the web server:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$currentdatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
print ($currentdatetime);
?>
```

And doing `http://www.mywebsite.com/gettime.php` you will get a string with the UTC web server time